# Como montar a expressão regular abaixo

Tags: regex

Estou tentando montar uma expressão regular e não estou conseguindo.

Como faço para montar uma expressão regular que aceite apenas números, barra e hífen?

Answer (score 3):

Esse é o dróide que você está procurando:

```
/[\d\/-]+/
```

Algumas particularidades da lista acima:

- a lista `\d` compreende todos os números
- o caractere `\/` representa uma barra; caso o delimitador da expressão regular fosse outro (por exemplo, `#`), não seria necessário escapar
- o hífen precisa ser o último elemento, já que no meio pode significar um *range* entre caracteres

Comment: Se você usar os delimitador `/` deve se escapar uma `/` que seja para captura, caso contraria ira gerar erro, pois sera interpretada como delimitador final. Solução alterar o delimitador, caso o linguagem permita, escapar a `/`.

Comment: É verdade, vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti podes escapar o hífen também. Assim fica seguro caso o AP use noutra ordem.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de montar essa expressão é usando um *range* de número.

Fica dessa forma:

```
[0-9\/-]+
```

Geralmente eu gosto de montar usando *ranges* (`0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `…`) ao invés de `\d` porque fica mais explícito.

Aqui você pode ver ela funcionando: https://regex101.com/r/uM3wC2/1

Comment: Não funciona. O seu padrão seleciona somente números. https://regex101.com/r/uM3wC2/2

Comment: Funciona sim. Adicione `/g` que ele pegará globalmente: https://regex101.com/r/uM3wC2/3 ; Não foi o que ele pediu, porém.

Comment: @zwitterion a regex está certa: _"números, barra e hífen"_. Juntando `g` como flag então apanha mais do que só o primeiro.

Comment: eu entendi que tem que ser números E barra E hífen. E não números OU barra OU  hífen. Se for OU o seu exemplo está correto. Pois vai selecionar o primeiro (E somente o primeiro) grupo ( como mostrei no exemplo https://regex101.com/r/uM3wC2/2 ). Se vc adicionar `g` vai apenas pegar as outras partes do OU. Mas não parecer ser o solicitado.

Comment: @zwitterion ele pediu uma expressão regular que aceite APENAS números, barra e hífen, mas não especificou qual a ordem ou frequência.
Se vc não usar o modificador `/g`, vai casar apenas esses 3 em qualquer ordem ou frequência numa `string`. Se usar o `/g` vai casar N  `tokens` de uma string. Note que essa expressão não casa espaços.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiquei meio na dúvida quanto a essa questão.
Veja que a regex sugerida por Rodrigo seleciona (algarismo,barra,hífem) mas tbm o primeiro algarismos OU a primeira barra OU o primeiro hífem SOMENTE (separadamente), o que aparecer primeiro. [Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/lX9pA2/4).  EU não sei se esse é o resultado desejado. Mas se for, usaria o modificador `g` para complementar a solução do Rodrigo. [Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/lX9pA2/3).

Assim ele pode fazer o match em todas as partes do texto onde encontre a string procurada, mais de uma vez.

Mas se for para aceitar unica e exclusivamente algarismoS,barra e hífem, tenta esse padrão `(\d+\/-)+`. [Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/lX9pA2/5).